# Is the past tense -ste suffix (e.g., "bebiste") related to the pronoun "te"?

Tags: verbos, etimología

**Not literally**, but etymologically/historically.

This might sound like a stupid question but the thought popped into my head and I was wondering if it had any merit.

Preterite verb forms for *tú* end in *-ste* (e.g., *bebiste*, *cantaste*, *conociste*), and I was curious if this suffix was related to the pronoun *te*, because it almost appears like these verbs could be some type of *tú* form with *te* appended (*bebis*, *cantas*, *conocis*).

Answer (score 5):

The verbal ending already existed in Latin conjugation. This is the **amo** (*amar*) indicative past perfect conjugation:

> amav-i
>
> **amav-isti**
>
> amav-it
>
> amav-imus
>
> amav-istis
>
> amav-erunt

Second person **amavisti** evolved **amaste** in Spanish.

In Latin the enclitic pronoun (suffixe) are not used. So there is no reason to think that this conjugation comes from the addition of the pronoun **te**.